# What assembly to target

Tags: assembly

I'm kind of confused about assembly. What kind of assembly does a compiler like GCC target, and how does it figure out what assembly to generate? How much do these types of assembly differ, is it a huge difference, or not as noticeable? How many types of assembly are widely used today?

Comment: Assembler languages are almost the "native" language of the CPU, and each CPU type have its own assembly language. High-level compilers like GCC have many code generators to generate code for all the different supported CPU architectures. How e.g. GCC know which target to select? Because when building the compiler someone set a *host* (which is the system you are building on) and a *target* (which is the target system the code will be generated for. The host and the target can be the same.

Comment: So all the modern intel processors, do they change their language thing often or rarely? And is that why some binary files have something-i386 etc prefixed, is that the kind of processor set/type/thing it supports?

Comment: The assembly of the Intel range of mainstream processors have been just about the same since the [8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086), there has just been more instructions added. Also note that on modern Intel processors, the assembly language isn't actually a one-to-one mapping to the actual instructions the CPU cores executes like it used to be. Instead the cores translates the assembly instructions to its actual native instruction-set.

Comment: And to more or less answer your question about which assembler language to target, it's usually *none*. Unless you want to work with small embedded systems, writing operating system kernels, highly optimized graphical engines, or similar systems then there's really no need to learn assembly. *Personally* I think you should anyway, as it will teach you more about how computers work at a lower level and give you better understanding of concepts such as pointers. And then it doesn't matter really *what* system you target, as just about any can be emulated today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What kind of assembly does a compiler like GCC target, and how does it
>   figure out what assembly to generate?

Each CPU family (*architecture*) has a different assembly and GCC is build to support many of these CPU families. You can pass an argument to GCC to indicate which architecture you want to target (this is called [cross-compiling](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) if you're compiling for an architecture different from the one you're compiling in).

> How much do these types of assembly differ, is it a huge difference,
>   or not as noticeable?

Usually each architecture is totally different and absolutely incompatible with others.

> How many types of assembly are widely used today?

Too many to list here, but most widely used architectures today are Intel x86 and x86-64 for PCs, ARM (and to a lesser extent, MIPS) for mobile/embedded devices. Simpler and smaller devices can use microcontrollers instead of full-featured CPUs.

> So all the modern intel processors, do they change their language
>   thing often or rarely?

Depends. Usually manufacturers try to keep compatibility with older models, although they can also decide to break it (i.e. [Intel's IA-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) architecture).

> And is that why some binary files have something-i386 etc prefixed, is
>   that the kind of processor set/type/thing it supports?

Yes. It's called *"architecture"*.

Comment: Awesome! So when Go says it supports "amd64 (a.k.a. x86-64); 6g,6l,6c,6a", what does this mean? Is amd64 one type of assembly, or a category of many?

Comment: amd64 is just another name for x86-64 architecture, because it was designed by AMD. It's a 64-bit retro-compatible extension for Intel's x86 architecture. I suggest you talk about architecture, not assembly, it's more correct :)

Comment: Ok! :) Thanks, 1 more haha, how do I tell what architecture I'm on myself?

Comment: Depends on the OS. In Linux you can do `uname -a`.